# What should happen with `await` when the expression after the keyword does not evaluate to promise?

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-next

I have a ES7 code like this.

```
async function returnsfive() {
  var three = 3;
  var threeP = await three;
  return threeP+2;
}

returnsfive().then(k=>console.log(k), e=>console.error("err", e))
```

What should happen at the `var threeP = await three` line?

Should the code continue as expected, or fail, because `three` is not a promise?

In [this repo](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait), it is mentioned as "Debatable Syntax & Semantics". I am not able to read through the official documentation to find the exact definition, since it's too technical.

Default babel.js transformation logs 5 as expected; however, `nodent` - a different transform - prints `TypeError: three.then is not a function`. Which is correct and why?

Comment: `async/await` is not part of ES7. It's a proposal.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for editing the tags!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [current working draft spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/#abstract-ops-async-function-await), the runtime should "cast" the awaited value to a promise first:

> **AsyncFunctionAwait ( *value* )**
>
> 1. Let `asyncContext` be the running execution context.
> 2. Let `promiseCapability` be `! NewPromiseCapability(%Promise%)`.
> 3. Let `resolveResult` be `! Call(promiseCapability.[[Resolve]], undefined, value)`.
> 4. ...

Step 2 and 3 combined is roughly equivalent to calling [`Promise.resolve(value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve), which creates a new promise that is resolved with the given value or - if the value is a thenable - will follow that thenable.

In other words: `await 3` is equivalent to `await Promise.resolve(3)`, and Babel implements the spec correctly.

nodent on the other hand [deliberately does not support awaiting a non-promise by default](https://github.com/MatAtBread/nodent#gotchas-and-es7-compatibility). There's a `wrapAwait` option available if you want all awaited values to be wrapped in a promise first, but the nodent documentation reports that this may affect performance.